# Impossible to run C# WPF software (Error 0xc0000374)

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I have a problem here and i need some help.

I work on a C# software in WPF, i have finished it, the program compile but do not run.

I've tried to search the problem using step by step run and it end on this line

`var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile") { FileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\Logs\" + DateTime.Now.DayOfYear + ".txt" };`

and

`var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget("logconsole");`

and i got this error : " Attempt to read or write protected memory. This often indicates that another memory is corrupted "

that happen randomly during execution but mostly while running theses lines of code.

If you got a solution i'll take it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF `Application` class does not have a `StartupPath` property.

You could add `System.Windows.Forms` as project reference and use `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath`

Alternative:

```
string appPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
               .GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName;
string appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(appPath);
```

To debug your code with finer granularity, you could rewrite it:

```
var fileName = Application.StartupPath;

fileName += @"\Logs\"; 
fileName += DateTime.Now.DayOfYear 
fileName += ".txt";

var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile");
logFile.FileName = fileName;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me !